# Differentiability of $z\cdot \operatorname{Im} z$ at 0

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Is $z \cdot \operatorname{Im} z$ differentiable at 0? Notes for a course i'm taking tells that yes, but i doubt it. So,

$$f(z) = xy+iy^2$$

I started with Cauchy-Riemann:
$$u_x = y \ne 2y = v_y$$
$$u_y = x \ne 0 = -v_x$$
I think this proves that the function no differentiable nowhere. But then i tried with limit at $z=0$ (x = y = 0):
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\xi+i\eta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\eta\xi+i\eta^2}{\xi+i\eta} = 0
\end{equation}
So, from the limit i see that it is differentiable. Why i have two different answers?

Comment: In your Cauchy-Riemann equations, you have the steps $y\neq 2y$ and $x\neq 0$, but this is assuming that $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. You've only prove the function is not differentiable when $z\neq 0$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks i just came to it. You could answer my question and i will accept it if you like.

Comment: Simply note that $f(0)=0$ and that $\lim\limits_{z\to0}\left|\frac{f(z)}z\right|=0$, which, together, imply that $f$ is differentiable at $z=0$ and that $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Yola: You saw fit to accept the only answer involving a nonexistent entity (the derivative of the Imaginary part). Please be aware that your TA might not accept this trick if you include it in your written solution (actually, if they are doing their job correctly, they certainly won't). What is odd here is that you received two other answers, both quite correct (plus my own previous comment, if I may).

Comment: i upvoted two answers which i understood. And accepted one which pointed me to my error. About Jose Carlos Santos answer i think he means $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(0+h)\operatorname {Im} (0+h) - 0\operatorname{Im}(0)}{h} = lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h\operatorname {Im}(h)}{h} = 0.$ Is that right interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong to conclude "differentiable nowhere" from

$$u_x = y \ne 2y = v_y,$$
$$u_y = x \ne 0 = -v_x.$$

Because 
$$u_x = 0 = 2\cdot0 = v_y,$$
$$u_y = 0 = 0 = -v_x.$$

at the origin.

---

Differentiability at the origin comes from

$$(z\text{ Im } z)'=\text{Im } z+z\text{ Im }' z.$$

Even though $\text{ Im }' z$ is undefined, multiplying that by $0$ results in $0$.

Comment: This is the best answer because it explains where the OP went wrong. The statements $y\ne 2y$ and $x\ne 0$ are false when $x=y=0$.

Comment: @Carmeister Odd comment, since the answer involves the nonexistent entity $\mathrm{Im}'$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z\operatorname{Im}z}{z}=\lim_{z\to0}\operatorname{Im}z=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Any function $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ such that $|f(z)| \le C|z|^2$ near $0$ is complex-differentiable at $0.$ This follows directly from the definition of $f'(0).$